# Restcomm build failed - unable to download mobicents Media version: 3.0.2.Final

Tags: restcomm

Trying to build RestComm-Core from source and getting following build fail message

> ```
> get-mobicents-media:
>    [echo] Downloading mobicents Media version: 3.0.2.Final
>    [exec] --2016-02-06 21:52:51--  https://mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com/view/MediaServer/job/Mobicents-MediaServer-4.x/24/artifact/bootstrap/target/mms-server.zip
>    [exec] Resolving mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com (mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com)... 23.21.63.208, 54.221.208.106
>    [exec] Connecting to mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com (mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com)|23.21.63.208|:443... connected.
>    [exec] HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
>    [exec] 2016-02-06 21:52:53 ERROR 404: Not Found.
>    [exec] 
>
> BUILD FAILED
> ~/RestComm-Core/release/build.xml:116: exec returned: 8
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed the URL was not correct in build.xml file

Wrong
`https://mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com/view/MediaServer/job/Mobicents-MediaServer-4.x/24/artifact/bootstrap/target/mms-server.zip`

Correct - change Mobicents to RestComm

```
https://mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com/view/MediaServer/job/RestComm-MediaServer-4.x/24/artifact/bootstrap/target/mms-server.zip
```